# Getting ID of first and last Neo blocks of certain type

Tags: plugin-neo

With the below `{{ module.type }}` outputs `'moduleFAQ'` but `firstFAQId` and `lastFAQId` don't output anything. Why is that?

```
{% for module in module.children.all() %}
    {% set firstFAQ = module.type('moduleFaq').one() %}
    {% set firstFAQId = firstFAQ ? firstFAQ.id : null %}
    {% set lastFAQ = module.type('moduleFaq').last() %}
    {% set lastFAQId = lastFAQ ? lastFAQ.id : null %}
    {{ module.type }} / {{ firstFAQ }} / {{ lastFAQ }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve a bit more? This is a loop so so you might not be able to get `lastFAQ` until the loop has finished running. I'm not familiar with Neo but if all you want are the first and last id of a certain block type, `{% set firstFAQId = module.children.type('moduleFaq').one() %}` and `{% set lastFAQId = module.children.type('moduleFaq').inReverse().one() %}` should work (not tested).

Comment: So a block can have some plain text, followed by a series of FAQs, followed by some more text. Before and after the FAQs, there needs to be a wrapping element. I'm already looping through `module.children.all` so I don't need to have that when looking for the block type. If you take that out, what I have is essentially the same as you.